# Simple coding error (potentially) in kernel code

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers

Here are the related structs:

```
typedef struct OS_BM {
  void *free;                     /* Pointer to first free memory block      */
  void *end;                      /* Pointer to memory block end             */
  U32  blk_size;                  /* Memory block size   */ 
  U32  owner_one;                   
} *P_BM;

typedef struct NEW {                           //struct ADDED BY ME
  void *free;
  U8 pid;
} *P_GH;
```

Here is the code in question (only the part "ADDED BY ME"):

```
void *rt_alloc_box (void *box_mem) {
  /* Allocate a memory block and return start address. */
  void **free;
#if !(defined(__TARGET_ARCH_7_M) || defined(__TARGET_ARCH_7E_M))
  int  irq_dis;

  irq_dis = __disable_irq ();
  free = ((P_BM) box_mem)->free;        
  if (free) {
   array[counter]->free=((P_BM) box_mem)->free; //ADDED BY ME- MAY NOT BE WORKING
   array[counter]->pid = rt_tsk_self();         //ADDED BY ME
   counter++;                                  //ADDED BY ME
    ((P_BM) box_mem)->free = *free;
  }
  if (!irq_dis) __enable_irq ();
#else
  do {
    if ((free = (void **)__ldrex(&((P_BM) box_mem)->free)) == 0) {
      __clrex();
      break;
    }
  } while (__strex((U32)*free, &((P_BM) box_mem)->free));
#endif
  return (free);
}

int free_owner (void *box_mem, void *box){ //FUNCTION ADDED BY ME
   int i; 

   for(i = 0; i<8;i++){
      if (box == array[i]->free;){            //MAY NOT BE WORKING
         if(rt_tsk_self() ==  (array[i]->pid)) 
         return (0);
      }
   }
   return (1);

}
```

**Code Description:** The first function is to do with memory allocation, but I need to added protection/ownership to the memory block that is allocated from the pool. That is why I am putting the memory block address as well as the process ID (returned from `rt_tsk_self()`) into an extra global array that I created. The second function just checks if the process with using the allocated block has the same ownership as the one created (again it uses `rt_tsk_self()`).

**Actual Problem:** The lines commented with "MAY NOT BE WORKING" don't seem to work as I am sure that I can put the process ID into the array as well as checking that it is in there, but I cannot do the same with memory block address. This is very likely to just be a simple coding error rather than conceptual.

Comment: could it be the line that says `counter++;` should instead say `counta++`?

Comment: Extraneous semicolon in the if expression?

Comment: sorry it is suppose to be COUNTER for all of them. I used counta in original code but I was afraid it might confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (box == array[i]->free;){            //MAY NOT BE WORKING
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
 if (box == *(array[i]->free)){            //MAY NOT BE WORKING
```

Also, somehow comparing void pointers make me, uneasy.

Comment: i am trying to compare addresses of box and the variable free from the
rt_alloc_box function

Comment: also if (box == *(array[i]->free)) doesnt seem to solve the issue as they are now different types